# Is there any way to differentiate the actions performed by the user and system in the Abp Audit Logging? C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, abp

Differentiation between actions of system and user. -Abp Audit Logs

I generated Entity history change tables using Asp.net boilerplate but could not find anything about the automatic changes made by the system. I want to know if there is any way possible to differentiate the actions of user and systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abp's audit logs are recorded through middleware. The actions performed by users are considered as requests and are included in the log. However, since the actions performed by the system itself are not requests, the middleware is not triggered and there is no log recording for these actions. In other words, the actions performed by the system are not already being logged.

Comment: Although the actions performed by the systems are not being logged, but in a sense the automatic changes that occur in an application are also the changes made by the system. For example, while placing an order, we input quantity required, rate, supplier etc. and the order number that will be generated is not an action of user.